# How to add commit messages to source code in gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

When I commit a file in gitlab, I enter a commit message which I can see it later in commit history. Is there any way for me to simultaneously add the same commit message to the source code also? Age old CVS has this feature.

I need this because Oracle codes have change comments inside the PLSQL source code so that people can see what changes have been made  outside of gitlab.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a job for the `commit-msg` hook?